# Selenium: Variables not accessible from other testcases

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, global-variables

I'm using Selenium in Visual Studio with NUnit to sort my testcases.

I am unable to access two string variables because they belong to two different testcases.

A simplified version of what my code looks like

```
namespace AutomatedTestCases
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass : BaseTest
    {
       private String A;
       private String B;
       [Test]
       public void TestCase1()
       {
          String A = "ABC123";
          Console.WriteLine(A);
       }

       [Test]
       public void TestCase2()
       {
          String B = "ABC123";
          Console.WriteLine(B);
       }
       [Test]       
       public void TestCase3()
       {
          Console.WriteLine(A);
          Console.WriteLine(B);
       }
       [Test]
       public void OrderOfTestCases()
       {
       TestCase1();
       TestCase2();
       TestCase3();
       }
   }
}
```

When I print the text from within the testcase ABC123 is printed.
But when I run them in order (OrderOfTestCases()) it prints nothing or null.

So it seems like the value "ABC123" is not stored in the variable between testcases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A` and `B` variable are accessible only in the methods where they are declared. If you want to access `A` or `B` outside of the methods where they were initially declared, you have to move the declaration at class scope.

```
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass : BaseTest
    {
        private string A = "ABC123";
        private string B = "ABC123";
    }
```

This means you can access `A` or `B` variables in any Test method which is from `TestClass` class.

In case you just want to define the variable and assign it's value in a test, you should simply use:

```
private string A;
private string B;
```

and in your `[Test]` method:

```
[Test]
public void TestCase1()
{
   A = "ABC123";
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to declare them there without giving them a value? Like this `private string A;` Since the specific values are not static I can not give them a value in beforehand like that. I need to run the inner testcases of that class to retrieve the data from certain elements of the webpage I'm testing.

Comment: The error message is gone but it seems like the value is not stored permanently. Please read updated question.

Comment: Remove `String` before `A` and `B` and try again. Let only `A` = "ABC123";